# I am trying to make something in my web page that, after pressing a button, randomizes three seperate images and then shows pieces of text related

Tags: html

I'm trying to make a website about a game, this game has items, characters and places and I'm trying to code something where, when a button is pushed, it will show a random item, place and character and then show text based on the image it shows, I am working with Html 4 and am a very novice coder

Comment: Hello Magnus, in this website we can help you only with a specific problem, you need to study your project and try with your own code, then if you have a specific problem return and post it here with an example.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.